# Querying Informix table using pyodbc produces ODBC SQL type -103 is not yet supported error

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, informix

I'm trying to query a table from an Informix database using pyodbc and write the results to a CSV file with the below code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

server = '***.***.***.***'
dsn= 'informixdb'
username = 'user'
password = 'user123'
csvFile = r"C:\temp\bookings.csv"

conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn=f'{dsn}', uid=f'{username}', pwd=f'{password}')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT FIRST 5 * from bookingsd"

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
df.to_csv(csvFile, index=False)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
import pyodbc, csv
    
server = '***.***.***.***'
dsn= 'informixdb'
username = 'user'
password = 'user123'
csvFile = r"C:\temp\bookings.csv"
    
conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn=f'{dsn}', uid=f'{username}', pwd=f'{password}')
cursor = conn.cursor()
    
sql = "SELECT FIRST 5 * from bookingsd"

rows = cursor.execute(sql)
with open(csvFile, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([x[0] for x in cursor.description])  # column headers
        for row in rows:
           writer.writerow(row)
```

Both produce the same error:

> ODBC SQL type -103 is not yet supported.  column-index=136
> type=-103', 'HY106'

It appears the error is occurring for the pyodbc cursor object (i.e. rows).  Does anyone know what this error is referring to?

Comment: The ODBC driver is returning a SQL type that pyodbc does not understand, presumably because it is not defined in the standard ODBC header files. What is the data type of the column in that table referring to "column-index=136"?

Comment: In Informix C code, `CLONGTYPE` is defined as `103` — I wonder if that's relevant.  If so, we need a discussion of why that is leaking through ODBC and/or PyODBC.

Comment: What is the schema of the `bookingsd` table?

Comment: The data type is CLOB.  Is this a limitation with pyodbc?

Comment: Try adding "NeedODBCTypesOnly=1" to the connection string to tell the ODBC driver to use CLOB/BLOBs as standard types. More info here (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.odbc.doc/ids_odbc_098.htm#ids_odbc_098)

Comment: Thanks, jsagrera!  That did it!

Comment: @jsagrera - Please consider posting your comment as an answer since it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Informix datatype CLOB are BLOB are not standard ODBC types, you may need to tell the ODBC driver to automatically handle those types.

You do that enabling the "Report standard ODBC types" feature within the ODBC driver by setting the "SQL_INFX_ATTR_ODBC_TYPES_ONLY" ODBC attribute or by adding a "NeedODBCTypesOnly=1" to the connection string.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=types-report-standard-odbc